# How to change PHPSESSID cookie domain name in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a WordPress site which sets the PHPSESSID cookie with domain name `www.example.com`.

I want it to set it to `.example.com` so I can use it in the subdomain.

Comment: I am unable to find the PHPSESSID cookie after login in the WordPress site. Can you show the screenshot where it is shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the domain calling `session_set_cookie_params()`.

Read the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Basically do something like:

```
 session_set_cookie_params ( 0, '/', 'example.com' );
```

If you are on PHP 7.3 you can do it like this:

```php
session_set_cookie_params ( ['domain' => 'example.com'] );
```

Call this early in execution. Setting this on your `wp-config.php` should be safe enough.

Comment: I have put session_set_cookie_params ( 0, '/', '.example.com' ); in wp-config.php and it worked.